# AMD Ryzen 7 1700X CPU on AX370-Gaming K7 Gigabyte Motherboard Audio Issue

Tags: bash, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Headphone audio port won't play any audio. The rear audio port is fine. To manually fix this problem, save the script below into a file called audio.sh and run the script as "sh audio.sh b|f" where b is for back and f is for front to switch between the back and front audio port (driver should be modified to mimic something similar automatically when the headphones are plugged into the front audio port):

Hope this helps someone else.

```
############

#!/bin/sh

usage="usage: sh audio.sh b|f"

in=$(pacmd list-sink-inputs 2>&1 | egrep index: | sed 's/.*: //')
echo "in=$in"

n=$(pacmd list-sinks | egrep index: | wc -l)
#echo "n=$n"
test $n = 2 && {
 pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,4
}

back=$(pacmd list-sinks | egrep 'index:|name:' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | egrep analog 
| sed 's/\tname:.*//;s/.*index: //')
echo "back=$back"
front=$(pacmd list-sinks | egrep 'index:|name:' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' | egrep hw | s
ed 's/\tname:.*//;s/.*index: //')
echo "front=$front"

test x"$1" = xb && {
 out=$back
}
test x"$1" = xf && {
 out=$front
}
test x"$1" = x && {
 echo "$usage"
 exit 1
}

echo "# $in -> $out"
pacmd move-sink-input $in $out
```

Comment: Hello an welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Thank you for your contribution and the script. Our question & answer format works much better if we strictly separate questions from answers. It would therefore be great if you separated your post and put the solution in an answer to your own question. We really encourage this.